# How to link a button to a form in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to load a form when clicking a button.

```
 private void btnAddRecordMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

This is my method.
The form name is Admin.java.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You probably don't really want to listen to mouse events - you probably want to be listening to action events instead.

Comment: It would be useful if you told us more about your environment (netbeans?) and showed us a little more code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
Admin form = new Admin();
form.setVisible( true );
```

I suggest you start reading the [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for the basics of using Swing. Maybe something like "How to Write an Action Listener".

And use proper terms. What is a form? We have to guess what you are talking about. There is no component by that name in Swing.

Comment: This question sounds very Netbeansy to me.  That thing talks about forms a lot.  Also, Luke has already asked a bunch of Netbeansy questions today.

Comment: Maybe it is but my answer still stands. Luke should learn how to write Swing code, not how to use an IDE. If you understand Swing then it should be easy to figure out the code required to show a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm i just had a problem like yours and I managed to sort it out... so I'm willing to share.

1. You need to select the option of JFrame form and that Mouse Event listerner will change to ActionEvent
2. Type that second code of yours to link the forms and make sure that the name is the same as the other form... I hope it could work because to me it just did work.